# Why I am getting error by placing self in the __repr__ method in the class in python?

Tags: python, self, repr

Why I am getting error by placing self in the **repr** method in the class? What is happening behind the scene when I **print(Employee.list_objects[0])**. Why I am getting error?

```
class Employee:
    list_objects = []

    def __init__(self,name,age,pay):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.pay=pay
        Employee.list_objects.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self} {self.name}, {self.age}, {self.pay})'

Employee1=Employee("Ali",23,50000)
Employee2=Employee("John",25,40000)
Employee3=Employee("Smith",29,70000)


print(Employee.list_objects[0])

Ouptut:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f1.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(Employee.list_objects[0])
  File "f1.py", line 11, in __repr__
    return f'{self} {self.name}, {self.age}, {self.pay})'
  File "f1.py", line 11, in __repr__
    return f'{self} {self.name}, {self.age}, {self.pay})'
  File "f1.py", line 11, in __repr__
    return f'{self} {self.name}, {self.age}, {self.pay})'
  [Previous line repeated 330 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why I am getting error by placing self in the **repr** method in the class? What is happening behind the scene when I **print(Employee.list_objects[0])**. Why I am getting error?

Comment: The expression `f'{self}'` calls `self.__repr__` which tries to evaluate `f'{self}'` which calls `self.__repr__` .... and so on until you reach the max recursion depth

Comment: @rdas Maximum recursion depth of python interpreter is 1000. Why it shows me   [Previous line repeated 330 more times]?

Comment: You can check the recursion limit with `sys.getrecursionlimit` & verify that. Though your time would be better spent fixing the infinite recursion in your code IMO.

Comment: @rdas I verified it's 1000